# How to efficiently find the date of the N-th occurrence of a specific weekday in each month within a given pandas DataFrame date range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have a pandas DataFrame with a date range, and I want to find the date of the N-th occurrence of a specific weekday (say, the third Tuesday) of each month within that range. I'm dealing with a large dataset spanning several years, so efficiency is crucial. Here's how my DataFrame looks:

```
import pandas as pd

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='12/31/2023', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
```

IDK if this fall under the umbrella of SO questions, bud i'd like a faster approach than just looping through everything. Is there a more efficient/pro way of doing this?

Comment: `freq='WOM-3TUE'`

Comment: @richard you should post it as answer for clarity

Comment: As it's not trivial, I added the answer to provide some more details and links to documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @richard in the comments, you should use the `WOM-3TUE` frequency in [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html). See [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) for more details on the frequencies (although this one is not clearly documented).

```
import pandas as pd
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='12/31/2023', freq='WOM-3TUE')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
```

Output:

```
         date
0  2020-01-21
1  2020-02-18
2  2020-03-17
3  2020-04-21
4  2020-05-19
          ...
43 2023-08-15
44 2023-09-19
45 2023-10-17
46 2023-11-21
47 2023-12-19
```